# Update a react-redux state too fast does not take the modification into account

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have an object stored in react-redux which contains multiple sub-objects, like:

```
MyObject =
{
  { id: 1, name: "object 1"}
  { id: 2, name: "object 2"}
  ...
}
```

This object can be updated very quickly multiple times, for example with a function like this:

```
function modifyMyObject() {
  //Load the object from Redux and create a clone to be modified
  let myObject = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.props.myObject))

  //Change the properties of my object
  ...

  //Update the object on Redux
  this.props.setMyObject(myObject)
}
```

However I noticed that if I call modifyMyObject() very quickly with different modifications, the object is not updated properly.
I guess that the state in redux does not have time to be updated before I try to make a new modification.

Here is the object slice :

```
import {createSlice} from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

const initialState = {
    value: {},
}

export const myObjectSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'object',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        setMyObject: (state, action) => {
            state.value = action.payload
        },
    },
})

// Action creators are generated for each case reducer function
export const { setMyObject } = myObjectSlice.actions

export default myObjectSlice.reducer
```

Is there a better way to handle these quick changes? Or do you have a suggestion to improve this code? Thank you!

Comment: Can you upload setObject() function?

Comment: Probably a race condition. `myObject` in your `modifyMyObject` function can hold stale state data. All of this logic seems to fit better in a reducer function instead of in a action creator. ("Change the properties of my object")

Comment: @VMT: sorry it was a typo in my example: I used directly setMyObject() which is the function in the slice.

Comment: I recommend using redux devtools to replay the actions and state updates step by step. This will be very helpful in figuring out exactly what's going wrong. https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-devtools/tree/main/extension

Comment: @HåkenLid: I installed DevTools, I can see that MyObject is changed multiples times in the same time frame as I suspected. Can you develop your first comment about moving the logic? I'm not sure to understand exactly what you mean.

Comment: As I said, `modifyMyObject` very much looks like the kind of logic that belongs in the reducer. But since you have left out any details of what is actually happening, it's very hard to give a specfic answer. 

The most important thing is here:  `let myObject = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.props.myObject))` Which copies a slice of the state to operate on. This object could be out of date by the time the `setMyObject` reducer updates the slice.

Comment: @HåkenLid: Your comment is right: the object copied with JSON.stringify is out of date when setMyObject is called. So, based on your remark I moved the logic of modifyMyObject() from App.js to the MyObjectSlice so that I don't have to use JSON.Stringify. Now I can modify directly the slice state, and it is working fine! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm posting here the solution to this problem which was suggested by HåkenLid:

Method which is NOT working: in App.js, create a copy of the slice.state, modify it and save it to Redux:

```
function modifyMyObject() {
  //Load the object from Redux and create a clone to be modified
  let myObject = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.props.myObject))

  //Change the properties of my object
  ...

  //Update the object on Redux
  this.props.setMyObject(myObject)
}
```

**The problem:** the object is out of date when saved.

**The solution:** In app.js:

```
function modifyMyObject(newObject) {
  this.props.updateMyObject(newObject) //call the function from the slice
}
```

In MyObjectSlice.js:

```
import {createSlice} from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

const initialState = {
    value: {},
}

export const myObjectSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'object',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        updateMyObject: (state, action) => {
        let newObject = action.payload
        //-> insert here the logic to update the object <-    
        ...
        state.value = newObject
        },
    },
})

// Action creators are generated for each case reducer function
export const { updateMyObject } = myObjectSlice.actions

export default myObjectSlice.reducer
```

Answer (score -1):

Are you trying `try/catch` block to handle `JSON.parse`? I hope this below can help you:

```
    function modifyMyObject() {
        function parseJSONSafely(str) {
            try {
                return JSON.parse(str);
            }
            catch (e) {
                console.err(e);
                // Return a default object, or null based on use case.
                return {}
            }
        }
        //Load the object from Redux and create a clone to be modified
        editedObject = parseJSONSafely(JSON.stringify(this.props.myObject))
        if (editedObject !== {}) {
            //Change the properties of my object
            editedObject['proterty'] = /* ... */
    
                //Update the object on Redux
            this.props.setMyObject(editedObject)
    }
}
```